# rambam saying if someone cheated you

Tags: rambam, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

I remember learning in Rambam that in cases where the one that was cheated can not prove it he says something like

> "the one that cheated me should be ..."

what is the correct saying, i am looking for it

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:torah-study]?

Answer (score -2):

> i just found it
>
> > מי שפרע מאנשי דור המבול ומאנשי דור הפלגה ומאנשי סדום ועמורה וממצרים בים הוא עתיד ליפרע ממי שאינו עומד בדיבורו
>
> http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Sales.7.2/he/Wikisource_Mishneh_Torah?qh=%D7%9E%D7%99%2B%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A2&lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all
>
> also kiszur shulchan aruch
>
> 62:15
>
> מי שנתן אפילו רק מקצת דמים על המקח   One who has given even only a
>   little money on a purchase,   או שרשם על המקח סימן בפני המוכר
>
> or has marked the object in the presence of the seller,
>
> או שאמר לו המוכר
>
> or the seller said to him:
>
> רשום מקחך ''Mark your purchase'',
>
> אף על פי שהוא בענין שלא קנה בזה
>
> even though he has not formally bought this object,
>
> מכל מקום כל החוזר בו
>
> in any event any one who goes back on it,
>
> בין הלוקח בין המוכר
>
> whether the buyer or the seller,
>
> לא עשה מעשה ישראל has not done an act becoming to a Jew,
>
> וחייב לקבל ''מי שפרע'
>
> ' and is obliged to receive a ''May He who took payment'',
>
> דהיינו שאוררין בבית דין ואומרים
>
> that is he is cursed in court and they say:
>
> מי שפרע מאנשי דור המבול
>
> ''May He who took payment from the people of the flood,
>
> ומאנשי דור הפלגה
>
> and from the people of disunity, (Tower of Babel)
>
> ומאנשי סדום ועמורה
>
> and from the people of Sodom and Amorrah,
>
> וממצרים שטבעו בים
>
> and from the Egyptians whom He drowned in the sea,
>
> הוא יפרע ממי שאינו עומד בדיבורו
>
> He will take payment from one who does not keep his word.

Comment: That's not talking about *cheating* someone where there's no proof; that's talking about someone who's made the first steps in a sale and then backed out before it was legally binding. The courts tell him "by the letter of the law you can do this, but breaches of faith like this destroy the world."